# Pass configuration parameter to custom Flink ProcessFunction

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to be able to pass in a configuration parameter to `MyFunction` which extends `ProcessFunction`. Is the only way for me to do that in my  parameter? I don't need it to be passed in with each element. Can I make use of the `open` method somehow?

```
public class MyProcessFunction extends ProcessFunction<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Row, RowTypeInfo>, MyOutput> {

    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Row, RowTypeInfo> value, Context ctx, Collector<MyOutput> out) throws Exception {
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a constructor to which you pass the parameter is a good approach.

The page in the Flink documentation on [Handling Application Parameters](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/application_parameters.html) has some related information.

You might think that you could somehow take advantage of the `Configuration parameters` parameter of the `open()` method, but this is a legacy holdover from the early days of the Flink project, and it isn't used by the DataStream API.

Comment: The current version does not support ds.filter().withParameters(configuration), right?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is to add a constructor. Or is the constructor approach not applicable in your use case? If so could you elaborate why?

```
private final String parameter;

public MyProcessFunction(String paramater) {
   this.parameter = parameter;
}
```

Then from main simply initiate the class with the appropriate parameter.

Edit:
To clarify, if your use case warrants it (if you are maintaining some state) then you should use open. But if you simply want to set some property you can just use a constructor.