# Configuration object passed in by Flink's AbstractRichFunction's open method

Tags: java, apache-flink

How could we utilize the configuration instance passed in by open() in AbstractRichFunction?
I've tried to add below logic to the job's main() but it said the configuration is unmodifiable (immutable as stated in javadoc)

```
var config = (Configuration) StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment().getConfiguration();
config.setString(/* a ConfigOption instance here */, "test-config-value");
```

I've figured out global job parameters would work for string values, but just wonder what we could do with the config instance in open(). Thanks.

FYI below works:

```
ParameterTool parameters = (ParameterTool)
            getRuntimeContext().getExecutionConfig().getGlobalJobParameters();
var value = parameters.getRequired("test-config-key");
```

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/66909820/2000823 answers your question.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70273620/2000823.

Comment: @DavidAnderson thanks i ended up passing the params via function constructor